# Solution to INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error on Android

Tags: android, android-sdcard, failed-installation

The `INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE` error is the bane of every Android developer's life. It happens regardless of app size, or how much storage is available. Rebooting the target device fixes the problem briefly, but it soon comes back. There are hundreds (if not thousands) of message board posts from people asking why the problem occurs, but the folks at Google are frustratingly silent on the issue.

There is a simple workaround. If your test device is running Android 2.2 or later then add the `android:installLocation` attribute to your application's manifest file, with the value `"preferExternal"`. This will force the app to be installed on the device's external storage, such as a phone's SD card.

For example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.andrewsmith.android.darkness"
          android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

This is more of a band-aid than a fix, and it may not be ideal if you want your finished app to install on the device's internal memory. But it will at least make the development process a lot less frustrating.

Comment: is it going to work for Android API level 4 or 1.6??

Comment: i got this msg in manifest file:-> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'installLocation' in package 'android' 
Pls help

Comment: @AndrewSmith: could you please answer your question? Just stumbled across this question during review because it's flagged as *not a real question*. While the flag is basically correct, it would be a shame if the solution will be lost.

Comment: First thing to do is: find out if the problem is actually space related! See [my answer on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19861111/825924) for details.

Comment: Very helpful. I encountered this problem when I am doing samples on LibGDX cookbook. This is a quick fix! Cheers mate.

Comment: Uninstall,
restart phone,
installing again, and again didn't give this error to me

Comment: This error appears when there is not enough space on your device. Uninstall some not needed apps and clear your memory and problem will gone

Comment: For me I had to restart my computer - Mac OS X Mavericks - and the error went away. Restarting eclipse was not enough.  Related to this, I noticed that my VirtualBox/Genymotion was also failing until I did the reboot

Comment: None of the suggestions worked for my device. It seems that Android is also reserving a fixed percentage of free space, just like any file system. My guess is around 10% but I can't confirm it. I've quickly searched the source for some config entry without success. Anyone know about this ?

Comment: I had the same issue. Fixed it with simple restarting of my Android mobile device ('LG L70')

Windows Command line:

    d:\>adb -s LGL70 install myapp.apk
    [100%] /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
            pkg: /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
    Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]

After restart the device:

    d:\>adb -s LGL70 install myapp.apk
    [100%] /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
            pkg: /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
    Success

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: Solved with trusty command: flutter clean

Comment: I had this error on android emulator. In android studio - AVD manager, there is an option to wipe data on a specific device. This fixed my problem

Comment: Can I increase the internal storage from 200 mb to 400 mb on the avd device and solve the problem? I am running android studio on windows 10

Comment: Restart computer worked for me.

Comment: Fastest solution: Open AVD Manager and choose Wipe Data in Actions for the device.

Comment: 'flutter clean' did not work for me.  What did work?  Delete everything in /data/app/  (See high-ranking answer below).  It was funny, I had just added custom icon images to the app, and I'm like "Whoa, did I make those icon images way too large?". Whew, no.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling is a not a solution (especially when you're working on an app that requires a login)

Answer (score 237):

This is only a **temporary workaround** and not a real fix.

After having this happen to me and not being pleased with the current responses I went to work
trying to figure it out from the AOSP source. I have found a **REAL** solution.

## Explanation

First off, a bit of (simplified) background on how [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) installs and updates

> The first time an app is installed:
>
> 1. The [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) file is saved as
>
>    ```
>    /data/app/<full.package.name>-1.apk  (1.apk)
>    ```
>
> When the app is to be updated:
>
> 1. The updated APK file is saved as:
>
>    ```
>    /data/app/<full.package.name>-2.apk (2.apk)
>    ```
> 2. The first version (1.apk) gets deleted.
>
> On our next update(s):
>
> 1. The new APK is saved as (1.apk) and (2.apk) is deleted (Repeat forever).

The issue that most of us are having happens when the application is updated, but deleting of the old APK fails. Which itself does not yet cause the update to fail, but it does cause there to be two APK files in `/data/app`.

The next time you try to update the app the system can't move its temporary file because neither (1.apk) nor (2.apk) are empty. Since File#renameTo(File) doesn't throw an exception but instead returns a boolean PackageManager, it doesn't have any way to tell why it returns INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE even though the failure had nothing to do with the amount of free space.

## Solution

Run:

```
adb shell "pm uninstall <full.packge.name>"
adb shell "rm -rf /data/app/<full.package.name>-*"
```

**OR**

Uninstall the app

Use your favorite method to delete **BOTH**:

> /data/app/<full.package.name>-1.apk
>
> /data/app/<full.package.name>-2.apk

Make sure nothing else blocks future installs in a similar way. In my case I had a `/data/app-lib/<full.package.name>-1` directory lingering around! In this case, an install to the [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital) worked, and a subsequent move to internal memory, too. (Creating `/data/app-lib/<full.package.name>` without the `-1` ending.)

## Why other "solutions" worked

- The code for installing to external storage is significantly different which does not have the same problems
- Uninstalling the app only deletes one version of the APK file in `/data/app`. That's why you can reinstall it once, but not update it.
- The amount of free space in an emulator isn't really relevant when this bug occurs

Comment: sad part, its temporary

Comment: Great hint! Had a related problem, but not the same: a directory named `/data/app-lib/full.package.name-1` blocked the direct install to internal memory. (I also found out that install to sdcard works!)

Comment: Thanks! In my case there was /data/app/<full.package.name>-1.odex only without *.apk, so the app was invisible in every app list. Deleting odex solved the issue.

Comment: I wonder how this can be done on a non-rooted device?

Comment: @Stan this works on a non-rooted device just use the sdk tools from android. Than adb is available.

Comment: In my case /data/app-lib/<full.package.name>-1 was the blocker. It got 3 native so libs. Deleting the folder helped and nothing else did.

Comment: @Msmit1993, you don't have access to the data directory on a non-rooted device. Having SDK and ADB does not matter.

Comment: For the truly lazy, here's a bash snippet:

`function fix_app { adb shell "pm uninstall ${1}; rm -rf /data/app/${1}-*; su -c 'rm -rf /data/app-lib/${1}-*'" }`

`$ fix_app com.facebook.katana`

Comment: my `data` directory is empty but still I am facing this issue, what to do?

Comment: I also tried `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` but all in vain, nothing is working in my case. I am using a real device for testing. What's the solution in this case?

Comment: I have this problem but I don't just have it with 1 app. Once it started I pretty much can't install/update any apps despite having plenty of space. How do you use this sort of approach, which I see all over the internet, when you don't have just 1 problem app?

Comment: my case was unusual -- I was working on a custom ROM that had a modified SELinux implementation, and in the course of experimenting I commented-out the platform signer tag in mac_permissions.xml; this apparently caused platform apps like PackageManager to never be assigned the seinfo value 'platform', and they wound up labeled with an scontext of untrusted_app.  Since PackageManager wasn't allowed to successfully write to /data/local, adb returned 'install failed: insufficient storage'

Comment: I had to clear `/data/local/tmp`

Comment: I get, `unexpected EOF`. How to fix it? THanks :)

Comment: In my case, I add to install the app with

    adb install -f ...

It was refusing to install it otherwise, even though I had 1.7GB free in internal memory; may be it was because I had no SDCARD.
But with the -f option, at least it worked, I don't know why...

Comment: Android Studio's AVD Manager now has an option to "wipe data" when you click on the "Actions" drop-down which seems to fix this issue as well.

Comment: Isn't `adb shell "pm uninstall <full.packge.name>"` equivalent to `adb uninstall <full package name>`?

Comment: The first command `adb shell "pm uninstall ...` failed for me with "`Unknown package`", however the 2nd command, deleting the APKs indeed fixed the problem.

...
The first time, after I went to run the app again, this fix no longer seems to work and I am facing the "INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFIENT_STORAGE" bug again :( 
....

Thank you for taking the time to look into this and figure out what is going on.

I'll post if/once I figure out why it doesn't keep working for me.

Comment: While there are a lot of great suggestions here, simply turning the emulated device off and on again also solved this for me, could be a fast easy solution also.

Comment: Of course uninstalling the app will fix the problem.  This isn't a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 123):

You need to increase the Android emulator's memory capacity. There are two ways for that:

1. Right click the root of your Android Project, go to "Run As" and then go to "Run Configurations...". Locate the "Android Application" node in the tree at the left, and then select your project and go to the "Target" tab on the right side of the window look down for the "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" field (sometimes you'll need to make the window larger) and finally paste "-partition-size 1024" there. Click Apply and then Run to use your emulator.
2. Go to [Eclipse's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) Preferences, and then select “Launch” Add “-partition-size 1024” on the “Default emulator option” field. Click “Apply” and use your emulator as usual.

Comment: Oscar, you presume that this is happening on the simulator.  In my case, it's happening on the actual device, which this answer doesn't address.

Comment: The second option didn't seem to work for me. However option 1 did! Great stuff! And worked with a 2.1 emulator.

Comment: This didn't work for me, presumably because I have snapshots enabled? How can I get the emulator to start Android from scratch with the new -partition-size option?

Comment: Lost on option 1 - I don't have a "Target" tab in ecclipse at this location.

Comment: 2nd option worked for me, thanks for the gud post @RacZo

Comment: @JeffAxelrod try this solution. I do not know if this work because I solved my problem by deleting the older version of my application, but is a suggestion. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7133508/1465756

Comment: how to set in Android Studio 4.2.1?

Answer (score 30):

Thanks for posting this question. I have some additional insights that may help some developers.

I am debugging my application on a device (not the emulator). The device has 21 MB free on `/data` (as revealed by "df" when doing "adb shell") and my app is only 5 MB. However, I did find that if I deleted other apps on the device (without rebooting the phone or restarting adbd), INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE would go away for a while and then come back.

So it seems that debugging my 5 MB app requires more like 20 MB of space in `/data`, and in addition something was leaking each time I debugged my app.

So I did "adb shell" and listed the ENTIRE `/data` directory with

```
cd /data
ls -a -l -R
```

And I looked at the 5000-line output to see where all the space was going.

I discovered **vast quantities of wasted space on my device in the `/data/klog` directory** in the form of old log files from months-old debugging sessions.

These were not my log files: they were created by some part of the Android infrastructure.

I deleted them and instantly saved 58 MB which was not attributed in the Settings app to any particular app. I have a small device so 58 MB is very significant (about 40%).

So far, I have not gotten INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE again after many runs. Let's hope that was the real issue, though the OP suggests that his device had plenty of space (but didn't say how much).

Hopefully some of you will also be able to escape INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE by periodically deleting `/data/klog/*`.

Or, you can at least do the `ls -a -l -R` in `/data` to see where all your space is going, if indeed there is really some (hidden) space issue.

Comment: any idea how to do this on a non-rooted phone?  I don't have access to the data diretory.  great post btw +1

Comment: Thanks for the info. FYI you can consolidate flags in Unix so that `ls` command becomes `ls -alR`

Comment: With root access do:
# su
# du /data | sort -g

to get a list of folders/files ordered by size

Comment: @JuanMaCuevas `du` lists folders only.

Comment: @Rich, try downloading the 3rd party app Astro File Manager. It's very popular and gives you access to your phone's files. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en

Comment: @rich My device is not rooted, I was able to delete most of the logs in /data/log (klog did not exist)

Answer (score 30):

The following helps:

- Open a shell to the device

  ```
  adb shell
  ```
- Navigate to the temp directory where the incoming APK is first copied

  ```
  cd /data/local/tmp
  ```
- List the available files and delete as desired

  ```
  rm * // use at your own risk, good practice to list files first
  ```

This has been reliable for me so far on an actual device.

---

**EDIT:** This turned out to be not as reliable a solution as the one above.

I tried a number of the solutions. Nothing really helped. Finally I found an app called [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm). That helped.

It says the functionality is limited on unrooted devices. Mine is rooted so it would be good to see hear from people effective it is in those scenarios and if it was just a fluke that it worked for me (it is an unpredictable problem anyway).

**NOTE:** I have nothing to do with the app. Just found it with a search.

Comment: It helped me.. Some of my previous application are stored in the tmp folder. After i removed those its working fine..

Answer (score 29):

I have solved it by including `android:installLocation="auto"` inside `<manifest>` tag in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Works indeed. Thanks.

Comment: This is the only fix that worked for me, on a real device. Thanks.

Comment: simply and nicely working.thanks

Comment: i added these line of code.but still getting this error `Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
adb: failed to install build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86.`

Comment: Best solution to work with emulator. Thanks!

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But can you explain why do we need to do this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 16):

I had added an additional line to the application's manifest file, which is `android:installLocation="preferExternal"`. by using this line it forces to install the app to the external storage. see the example below,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nasir.phonegap"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal" >
```

Answer (score 12):

I tried the following:

- Restarted my device
- Deleted previous APK
- Rebuild my APK
- Uninstall my previous copy in the device
- Reinstall

Check if it works the same with you.

Comment: Yep, restarting the device was the only one to work (after trying several solutions from this page)

Comment: Restarting the device work :)

Answer (score 11):

A related issue on the emulator is when there isn'y any space left in the `/data` partition.

For example,

```
% adb shell df

Filesystem             Size   Used   Free   Blksize
/dev                   252M    32K   252M   4096
/mnt/asec              252M     0K   252M   4096
/mnt/obb               252M     0K   252M   4096
/system                154M   154M     0K   4096
/data                   64M    57M     6M   4096
/cache                  64M     1M    62M   4096
```

Here is a sample view of the `/data/app` directory:

```
% adb shell ls -l /data/app

-rw-r--r-- system   system      19949 2011-10-12 17:09 CubeLiveWallpapers.apk
-rw-r--r-- system   system      27670 2011-10-12 17:09 GestureBuilder.apk
-rw-r--r-- system   system      34341 2011-10-12 17:09 SoftKeyboard.apk
-rw-r--r-- system   system      20151 2011-10-12 17:09 WidgetPreview.apk
```

I removed the extra [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) files. It seems upon every install you get a new APK file. Just remove the extra APK files.

For example,

```
adb shell rm /data/app/com.brooklynmarathon.calendarapi2-1.apk
```

Comment: 1. run "adb shell"     2. cd into each directory in data, and find the ones with big useless files.     3. delete them using "rm (filename)"    4. my recurring problems are with trash like "ApiDemos" and "dalvik-cache" (just delete the whole contents of that one)

Answer (score 10):

In my case failure was caused by `com.android.providers.media` app. I faced this on x86 android emulator. What did I do:

```
$ adb shell df
Filesystem             Size   Used   Free   Blksize
...
/data                  224M   209M    14M   4096
....
```

Too low free space on `/data`

```
$ adb shell du /data
...
409870  /data/data/com.android.providers.media
...
```

Almost all was consumed by single app! It's system app so I consider better not to delete it. Instead I cleaned up app data.

```
$ adb shell pm clear com.android.providers.media
Success
$ adb shell df
Filesystem             Size   Used   Free   Blksize
...
/data                  224M     8M   215M   4096
...
```

Disk was cleared and app installed successfully.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. After 2 hours! :)

Comment: For me this solution worked: 
https://youtu.be/6k0edzApQXU

Answer (score 8):

Answering to the very first post of this topic...

Symptom : Some app don't install, saying there is no space
and in reallity there is plenty of space free on both internal and external storage !!!
Solution: disable external installation by default.

Setting external install by defaut with this:

```
adb shell pm set-install-location 2
```

Makes install impossible on many apps that can't install externally (such as adblock + or so)

Then the solution is

```
adb shell pm set-install-location 0
```

Or

```
adb shell pm set-install-location 1

0: auto (if one is full - or irrelevant !!! - it select the other)
1: internal
2: external
```

Comment: I was starting to think this phone's internal storage was broken, but the setting the install location to 1 fixed the "insufficient space" issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

As this issue still exists, I thought I'd add something to [RacZo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-to-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error-on-android/5616720#5616720) for development purposes. If you're not using the [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) plugin or for whatever reason you don't have the source, but just the .apk, you can increase the partition size from the command line using the same option when you launch the emulator:

```
emulator -avd <emulator name> -partition-size 1024
```

As far as I know, This option is not documented at developer.android.com, so I thought I'd post it here so people might find this solution.

Comment: this is by far the best option because doesn't involve updating any file nor using any application, just `avd`

Answer (score 7):

I feel a bit weird writing this, but I can't be 100% sure that it's **not true** in **some cases** (it worked for me). If you had the following symptoms:

- You've been working using a physical device (in my case, Samsung Galaxy Ace),
- You've been developing for a couple of days straight,
- **Your phone was connected all the time**, day and night.
- You started getting this error after a couple of days, and it kept getting worse.
- **None** of the other answers worked for you.
- You're as resigned as I was...

Then, try this:

- Unplug your phone when you're not working!

I unplugged my phone and let it rest for ENTIRE DAY. My battery wore off a little. After this, I reconnected it and started debugging again. Everything worked fine this time! And I mean really REALLY fine, just as before.

Is it possible that this error might be due to some **battery-related hardware stuff**? It still feels weird thinking this way, but now I keep disconnecting my phone every now and then (and for the night) and the problem didn't return.

Comment: This happens to me all the time - on all my devices. During the cause of a day things usually start to fail at the end of each day. This is so annoying and its pretty amazing Google has not fixed this yet...

Comment: Same behaviour for me but reboot of the phone solved my problem persistently.

Answer (score 6):

**Emulator solution**

Open your `.Android` directory. Usually in your home directory. Then go to `avd` and then open the directory that has the name of the avd you would like to change.

Now edit the `config.ini` file and add the following line or modify the following line:

`disk.dataPartition.size=1024`

Where `1024` is the size you would like to use in MB. Save the file and then start your emulator with `wipe user data` checked. Your emulator should now have the new size.

Comment: Answer written in 2012, working wonderfully well in 2022.

Comment: Working in 2023. For those who can't find the folder, open your Android Studio IDE > Open device manager > click "Show on disk" - see this image  https://i.postimg.cc/rwqxRQfD/xo.png

Answer (score 5):

**Samsung Galaxy Ace** advertises 158 MB of internal storage in its specifications, but the core applications and services consume about 110 MB of that (I used the task manager on the device to inspect this). My app was 52 MB, because it had a lot of assets. Once I deleted some of those down to 45 MB, the app managed to install without a problem. The device was still alerting me that internal storage was almost full, and I should uninstall some apps, even though I only had one app installed.

After installing a release version of the .apk bundle and then uninstalling it, my device displays 99 MB of free space, so it might be debugging information cluttering up the device after all. See [Louis Semprini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-to-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error-on-android/8126572#8126572).

Answer (score 4):

**The solution is simple.**

Open up the AVD Manager. Edit your AVD.

Down in the hardware section, there are some properties listed with "New..." and "Delete" to the right of it.

Press New. Select Data Partition size. Set to "512MB" (the MB is required). And you're done. if you still get issues, increase your system and cache partitions too using the same method.

It's all documented right here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html

Comment: Data Partition is not an available option with the Google API Level 14

Comment: This is how it works for me! Even now 10 year later! thanks!

Comment: Link is broken :/

Answer (score 4):

Just uninstall the application from emulator either from command line or go to settings and uninstall the application. This will stop the error from coming.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem with my new Nexus 4 and an APK built with Adobe AIR. I already had android:installLocation="preferExternal" in my manifest. I noticed I was also calling `adb install` with the `-s` option (Install package on the shared mass storage such as sdcard.) which seemed like overkill.

Removing the `-s` flag from `adb install` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: +1, good one, -s should only used if overriding previous installed build.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround:

Compile as 2.1 without `android:installLocation="preferExternal"`.

OK?

Compile as 2.2 including `android:installLocation="preferExternal"`.

This will still install on SDK version less than 8 (the XML tag is ignored).

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question because I was getting this error using the Sideload Wonder Machine to install apps to my actual phone.  I found the problem was that I had multiple .apk files in the /payload directory.  I thought this was something that was supported, but when I removed all but one .apk, the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a real device, you've simply run out of internal memory. Just go to Android settings -> *Applications*, and move some apps to the SD card or uninstall some apps.

If you're using the emulator, see [RacZo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-to-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error-on-android/5616720#5616720).

Comment: We're talking about the insufficient storage error which comes up when there's plentiful available storage.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same error when I tried to batch install about 50 apps in the [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital) directory using the [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge) shell after a full ROM update:

```
for x in *.apk; do pm install -r $x; done
```

Some of them installed, but many failed with the error INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE. All the failed apps had space in their name. I batch renamed them and tried again. It all worked this time. I did not do reboot or anything. May be this is not the problem you guys are facing, but this might help someone searching with the same problem as I faced.

Comment: Also I notice that when I miss spell the app name sometime this same error comes. It's a misleading error message in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't connect your android device with usb while trying to run the emulator

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your application on an emulator, and if this problem persists, check your notification manager. If it shows you an icon and notification about "Phone memory is full", that means you have already installed so many applications on your emulator. Uninstall several applications which you don't want currently from "Settings >> Manage Application >> Select Application >> Uninstall".
That Set.
Now re-run the program.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error today, when using my phone for testing/debugging with Eclipse.

My error was that I used Norwegian special character ("æ", "ø", "å") in the application name. When I refactored the app name (using "o" instead of "ø") the app was installed correctly..

Probably not your problem, but could be note for other people getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

After trying out everything else in this thread, I found out my own problem was because the path to the .apk file was too long. So I cd'ed to the directory where the .apk was in and did:

```
cd /Very/Long/Path/To/Package/
adb install mypackage.apk
```

instead of

```
adb install /Very/Long/Path/To/Package/mypackage.apk
```

And it worked...installed just fine.

Just thought this might help someone else.

Comment: I might add, that making the directory a symbolic link allowed me to make builds from the IDE and debug: ln -s /Users/abc/a\ ridiculously\ long\ directory\ path/subpath/subsubpath/subsubsubpath/ shortpath

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem, and I did a "Factory data reset", and it worked fine after that.

Comment: I really would not recommend this as a solution. Total overkill.

Comment: It wipes your /data, that frees up some space so installations will work again. A very blunt instrument and not a solution. The error may come back after a few apps.

Comment: This is the equivalent of the doctor saying: I don't know what's wrong with your arm so I'm cutting it off.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it got fixed by increasing the extended memory of eclipse, by  changing the value of **-Xmx768m** in **eclipse.ini**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up uninstalling the app from the device and then re-installing it back in Eclipse. This is a problem I get all the time on my device from regular use, but today I got that message from development.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't have root access on my phone and am unprepared for my app to be installed on the SD card. 15 MB of space is available on `/data/` and my application is under 2 MB.

For a while I got by; cleaning the [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) project and restarting the phone, but eventually that stopped working (probably after an update).

Cleaning my application cache has solved the problem for me and doesn't require a restart of the phone or uninstallation of the app.

There are applications on the market which you can use to clear the cache of multiple applications at once. Search for "clean".

Answer (score -1):

A bit time consuming, but it should work in any case:

- Install a file manager, like [Adao Task Manager](http://www.handster.com/task_manager.html?pos=2), on your phone.

Connect via USB and enable USB storage. Copy the [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) file from your local build to the phone (you might need to allow unknown sources under application settings).

Then just tap the APK file and [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) will install it. Like I said, it's time consuming, but it might be faster than rebooting every now and then.