# Insufficient storage problem in HTC Wildfire

Tags: android, debugging, device

I am running Froyo on my HTC Wildfire. I have 17 MB storage free in my phone. The .apk I'm trying to install on the phone is 2.7MB but I get this wierd **Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE**. I'm using Eclipse and have enabled debugging on my device. I was able to install binaries with the size of 11 MB with the same free storage space a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backed up my data and performed a hard reset. Now works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem putting this in the AndroidManifiest.xml file:

**android:installLocation="preferExternal"**

just after:

android:versionName="1.0"

in the  tag.

Hope someone else benefits from this answer.
This way the apk file is installed if possible in sd card.

Answer (score 1):

Hard reset only works shortly.. then insufficent storage will continue to show on a pop up adviser on your mobile htc wildfire s. Try history eraser that can be dowloaded in the market. or any other cache and cookie cleaners, read description frist and make sure to back up all your phones data on your google account.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this before as well and haven't found one solution that works reliably so here are a couple of things to try:

1) Restart the phone
2) Uninstall any previous builds of the app on your phone
3) Restart adb by killing it off in your task manager (it will auto-restart when killed)

Comment: I have tried everything you have suggested and I have also uninstalled every app I had on my phone. But this is still getting on my nerves :(

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your device would works, and the following link is a same question with answers.

[Solution to INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-android-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error)