# runtime error in eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse

few days before when i was trying to run my apps the following type of error used to occur

```
[2011-02-24 20:33:41 - FlashCard] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
[2011-02-24 20:33:41 - FlashCard] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-02-24 20:33:41 - FlashCard] Launch canceled!
```

i used to close the eclipse or shut down my system, then it gets cleared.

Later it happens to occur often, i got a suggestion from stack overflow to enter command
adb start-server and adb kill-server in run cmd, the idea worked only for two days.

Right from today morning i am trying to run all my apps and the same error continues.

The adb server idea is not working, i have tried updating my eclipse too.

i am posting this just to get an idea about this problem, as i am new to android development and java.

if anyone have any solution  or idea pls share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried freeing up space on your device/emulator by uninstalling apps?

Comment: Sounds like a plan to me.  If it's failing to install because of insufficient storage then ensuring you have sufficient storage might stop it from failing to install.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below link for the solution

[Solution to INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-android-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error)

and top of this try to clear other application's data from the setting->application->manage application