# emulator size problem

Tags: android, size, storage, emulation

I got several times the same INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error.
I deleted and recreated a new AVD but it's the same.
To have it running normal I have to start from the shell because if I start from SDK and AVD manager or just pressing Run in Eclipse it start but gives me this error.
I tried to change cache partition size in the hardware options but nothing happen.
Is there a way to increase the emulator storage permanently without to use the shell every time?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might this be the solution you are looking for?

[Solution to INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-android-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error)