# How to give max size vm heap and ram size and partition in emulator in honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

How to give max size vm heap and ram size and partition in emulator in honeycomb?.I have run the large application with apk size 89.6mb but

```
 I am getting Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
```

I had given

```
 vm.heapsize 48
disk.cache.partition.size 1024mb
hw.ramSize 512
sdcard size 1 gb
```

still i am getting error can anybody help to solve this problem
Thanks

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-android-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error

Answer (score 1):

Open up your  Android Virtual Device Manager (assuming you're using that), and select your emulator.

Click Edit, and simply change the values you need.
My assumption is that your heapSize is too low (I usually set it to at least 25% of my set ram size just to be sure), considering your SD card space is 1 GB.