# How to increase size of internal memory in Google tv emulator

Tags: memory, emulation, internal, google-tv

I would like to install application in google tv emulator, but it don't install because of insuffient internal memory.

I have tried
1) disk.dataPartition.size=1024 in avd config ini file
2) emulator -avd  -partition-size 1024 -wipe-data

But without any results. Inernal memory size is only 12 MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some posts on SO about increasing internal memory on Android emulator, the same should work for Google TV emulator:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5616720/251956

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3945915/251956

Answer (score 1):

-partition-size does **NOT** work.

this is a Google TV add-on bug.

`vim <android-sdks>/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/skins/720p/hardware.ini`

change
`disk.dataPartition.size=128`
to
`disk.dataPartition.size=128m`

see

- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33697
- http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=104