# Google TV Addon Android Emulator Low Space Notification

Tags: java, android, google-tv

I am using Google Tv Addon for android with eclipse, My emulator runs fine but on start it gives a notification message of Low On Space Even If i give size of about 1000 MiB on creating the AVD it shows the same error. please help.Thanks!

Getting this in console:

com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No space left on device

Regards,
Muhammad Tahir Ashraf

Comment: this could resolve your issues!good luck

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-android-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error/5616720#5616720

Comment: @gerard: that seems like the right answer. Could you please add it as a answer instead of comment, so that we can consider this question answered? :)

Comment: Thanx for the comment but I have tried this but it's not working iam still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm suffering the same issue and I think this is a bug.

I've created a bug report here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33697

feel free to star it and add comment / information to it.