# adb install fails with message Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE] even after rebooting the sytem and emulator

Tags: android

adb install command fails even after rebooting the emulator and with following output

```
adb install app-debug-unaligned.apk
1687 KB/s (54880947 bytes in 31.754s)
pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-debug-unaligned.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
```

The following is the "adb logcat" outpu

```
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/dalvikvm(  378): GC_CONCURRENT freed 554K, 11% free 6060K/6788K, paused 27ms+38ms, total 347ms
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/dalvikvm(  378): GC_CONCURRENT freed 855K, 14% free 5884K/6812K, paused 17ms+26ms, total 190ms
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/dalvikvm(  378): GC_CONCURRENT freed 679K, 14% free 5882K/6812K, paused 29ms+11ms, total 312ms
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
^[3D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/dalvikvm(  378): GC_CONCURRENT freed 670K, 14% free 5890K/6812K, paused 19ms+72ms, total 397ms
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  378): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
D/AndroidRuntime( 1136):
D/AndroidRuntime( 1136): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 1136): CheckJNI is ON
D/dalvikvm( 1136): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1136): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1136): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1136): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1136): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1136): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
E/memtrack( 1136): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
E/android.os.Debug( 1136): failed to load memtrack module: -2
D/AndroidRuntime( 1136): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
I/installd(   58): free_cache(77280870) avail 51847168
W/installd(   58): Couldn't find Android in /data/media/0/
I/installd(   58): Collected cache files: 31 directories, 2 files
I/installd(   58): DEL (mod 1421576242) /data/data/com.android.launcher/cache/widgetpreviews.db
I/installd(   58): DEL (mod 1421576242) /data/data/com.android.launcher/cache/widgetpreviews.db-journal
W/ActivityManager(  378): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/app-debug-unaligned.apk
D/dalvikvm(  378): GC_EXPLICIT freed 133K, 14% free 5878K/6812K, paused 5ms+9ms, total 119ms
D/AndroidRuntime( 1136): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm( 1136): GC_CONCURRENT freed 124K, 19% free 568K/696K, paused 13ms+10ms, total 38ms
```

The development is on ubuntu vm. The apk was getting installed and working fine for some time before this problem occured. How to debug this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You might find interesting the responses at these questions:

- [Solution to INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4709137/1292300)
- [“Insufficient Storage Available” even there is lot of free space in
  device memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16818049/1292300)