# After I run my program about 6 times from eclipse. get " INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE

Tags: android

I'm developing a puzzle app that has a LOT of graphics.  It was giving me a lot of memory errors.  I'm now nulling out all the bitmap pointers, which seemed to fix the problem.

The ap runs find if I run if for a very long time, but...... after I run it for about 6 times, it will no longer run from the Eclipse IDE.  I get a " INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE" error.  I can't find any memory links (now logging the free memory).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a memory leak, you have a less disk storage. You have to check storage available on your mobile/emulator. Try delete/uninstall unnecessary files/application. If your using emulator then increase its storage.

Comment: Hi, the error is on the device.  So my program should be bug free??? I'm assuminbg you cannot fix this issue on the device just the emulator??????

Comment: Yes your programm is bug free. As you are testing on device so you have to uninstall some other application so that your application can get sufficient storage to install.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the Android emulator memory capacity. The link can be helpful - [Solution to INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-android-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error) .