# Any new solution to Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Does anyone have any other suggestions regarding the Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE] error?

I tried writing to external but I get the same error or media not found error. 
 - [Solution to INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-to-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error-on-android)

I also tried adding -partition-size 1024 to the setup and disk.dataPartition.size=1024MB to the avd configuration but no luck. 
 - [How to increase storage for Android Emulator? (INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239330/how-to-increase-storage-for-android-emulator-install-failed-insufficient-stora)

I've tried uninstalling the apk from the emulator. I really don't understand why this doesn't work. If I'm removing something, how does this not create space?  Plus, it's an emulator, why doesn't it just partition more space if my pc can handle the request?

I've tried rebuilding and cleaning project (although idk why this would work but I saw it posted somewhere) and I also tried re-defining another device definition but same error (obviously).

I'm using intellij IDEA.  Does anyone have any other suggestions to this annoying error message.  Currently I'm having to restart my emulator each time which is a waste of nearly 20 minutes each time I want to test.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of emulator are you testing on?

Comment: Make sure you have read-write permission rights for the storage in a manifest file. To increase the speed of an emulator I advise to install and use Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager, http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Comment: @MorrisonChang How do I get the emulator version?  I went to AVD manager - tools - about and it says android sdk Manager Revision 23.0.2, add-on XML Schema #7, Repository XML Schema #10.  Is this the correct information?

Comment: @user3806621 ok cool. I found information on the SD card emulation.  I'm hoping creating yet another AVD and redefining the sd card for it resolves the issue...http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#sdcard

Comment: @cjayem13 I meant which API level emulator are you testing on, e.g. API 18,19 or L.

Comment: @MorrisonChang  o0o0o0o! whoops! I'm using api 19.