# Unable to install app

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-install-apk

I am trying to run application in my device, But the android studio shows following error:

```
open: Permission denied
pkg: /dasta/local/temp/"packagename"
Failed: [INSTALL_FAILED_ISUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
```

There is 2.3 gb space available in my phone.
I tried adding this to manifest:

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

But it didn't help.
Any Solutions? I tried clearing residuals, cache, uninstalling app and restarting device, android studio and even my laptop
Please someone help.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the previous version of the same app uninstall it and then try.
and it is because of your internal storage space, try moving your internal apps to external storage.

Comment: this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-to-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error-on-android

Comment: i did that.. didn't help