# How to fix the insufficent storage in Android project running

Tags: android

When I am running the Android project in Android Studio on an external device then it is showing the following error message

> INSTALL FAILED AND INSUFFICIENT STORAGE

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: This problem was resolved and I give you the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-to-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error-on-android
Good luck

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility that the problem isn't a memory storage. 
Sometimes Android fails while updating your app and generates several packages with different names of your app. And, in simple words, next time Android won't understand which package it should update.

Next time try this:

**Run**

```
adb shell "pm uninstall <full.packge.name>"
adb shell "rm -rf /data/app/<full.package.name>-*"
```

These commands will delete all versions of your app and the problem should disappear.

Comment: Please, add some more details to the answer. What will happen after running this commands?

Comment: Especially: do you think it will work better than the troubleshooting provided in the other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34829967/2910)

Comment: @benc most of the cases (but not all, of course) the problem is not just a storage space

Answer (score 0):

This error comes if your device dont has memory required by your App(Project).

**Solution:**
Just remove apps which you dont needed or get a device with more storage space.

Comment: my device has alot of space in gbs but it still show that mesage