# Android INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I know that this is a quite common issue in android development, but the thing is that I do not have an SD card on my android device, so when I write `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` in my manifest, I get Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE]. Any idea how to fix it without SD card?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Just remove that line and it'll install the app  on your internal memory. Please tell me if that's not what you want to happen.

Comment: When I compile my app without that line, I get INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE. That is a common android issue and a particular solution is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-to-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error-on-android, but it does not really work for me, because I do not have SD card.

Comment: You can declare installLocation="auto", which means that your application may be installed on the external storage, but you don't have a preference of install location. You have enough memory on your device? I know my phone won't let me install from play store even if I have 400mb and app takes up 20mb. It needs some free space for some reason.

Comment: I had 350mb available, reallocating memory to 1gb solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I will just put it into the answer so you can accept it or whatever.. just close this thread then :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare installLocation="auto", which means that your application may be installed on the external storage, but you don't have a preference of install location. You have enough memory on your device? I know my phone won't let me install from play store even if I have 400mb and app takes up 20mb. It needs some free space for some reason.

It's quite a common thing, just free up some more space and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Fixed it with simple restarting of my Android mobile device ('LG L70')

Windows Command line:

```
d:\>adb -s LGL70 install myapp.apk
[100%] /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
```

After restart the device:

```
d:\>adb -s LGL70 install myapp.apk
[100%] /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
Success
```