# Why am I unable to run my PhoneGap application on my mobile device?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, lg

After using the `ionic run --device android` command to run my app on my device, I get the following error: `install_failed_insufficient_storage`

[image]

My device is a LG phone with Android 4.0.4 and I have enabled USB debugging, I can't figure out what the problem is, can anyone help out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solution to INSTALL\_FAILED\_INSUFFICIENT\_STORAGE error on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-to-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is saying you don't have sufficient storage on the device.  So, try deleting some apps or photos or something.