# Why do I get the Error: ADB exited with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, dart

If I want to start a simple app, which I used a few weeks ago without an error, I get an error.
That´s he error discription:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM J530F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameterformat falsch -
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\App Entwickeln\Projekte\test_app\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
Error launching application on SM J530F.
```

Comment: Did you check the available disk-space on the device you are trying to launch it on? The `INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE` indicates that it thinks that there is not enough space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same Problem and the solution is deleating something from your device. The Problem is, that the storeg is full

Answer (score 1):

From: [Solution to INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-to-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error-on-android)

> Solution Run:
>
> adb shell "pm uninstall " adb shell "rm -rf
>   /data/app/-*"
>
> **OR**
>
> Uninstall the app
>
> Use your favorite method to delete BOTH:
>
> /data/app/-1.apk
>
> /data/app/-2.apk
>
> Make sure nothing else blocks future installs in a similar way. In my
>   case I had a /data/app-lib/-1 directory lingering
>   around! In this case, an install to the SD card worked, and a
>   subsequent move to internal memory, too. (Creating
>   /data/app-lib/ without the -1 ending.)

For me the second solution worked!