# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE] when attempting to run flutter app on android emulator on MacOS

Tags: flutter, macos, android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I have been dealing with a very persistent error when attempting to run a flutter app on an Android Emulator (Android Virtual Device launched through Android Studio) through VS Code. Here is a screenshot of the errors: [image: Here is a screenshot of the error log]

I have attempted to wipe data & cold brew both my emulators & reopen the application folder to no avail. I am beginning to feel hopeless. If anyone can help me at all, I would really appreciate that. Thank you in advance :)

PS: here is how the emulator looks
[image: emulator]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solution to INSTALL\_FAILED\_INSUFFICIENT\_STORAGE error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-to-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error-on-android)

Answer (score 15):

if you wiped the emulator's data and it is still showing the error, try to increase your emulator's space,

1. Tools
2. AVD Manager
3. Locate the emulator you want to increase space, click the drop down
4. Edit
5. Show advanced settings
6. Edit the Internal storage
7. Restart the emulator if it's running

**NOTE**: Newer android studio versions do not have the **Edit** option inside the dropdown, it was moved next to the dropdown menu (The edit icon)

Comment: I can't find the 'show advanced settings' when I click the drop down :/ do u know how to access it on Mac?

Comment: Sorry, missed a step, after clicking the dropdown > Edit > Show advanced settings

Comment: The only options I get are: (duplicate, wipe data, cold boot now, show on disk, view details, Delete) :( all the other answer instruct the same thing, I don't know what's wrong with my AVD manager

Comment: Try to close the project
File > Close project
Then you will have the latest projects list,
next to **open** button, you will find a menu button, click it and AVD Manager
does that dropdown has the **Edit** option?

Comment: nope its pretty much the same.. I don't have any project open on Android Studio tho, just on VS Code, but Im accessing the AVD manager through Android Studios

Comment: It's weird that you don't have that option in the dropdown!
What is your android studio version?

Comment: Chipmunk | 2021.2.1

Comment: I just updated my Android Studio to your version, The `Edit` option was replaced with the Edit icon to the left of the dropdown

Comment: omg! yeah I see the icon! so do I just set the internal storage to some arbitrary big number?

Comment: Preferred to be multiples of 1024
1536
2048
...

Comment: I put it to 10240 MG & I'm STILL getting the same error. adb: failed to install  Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]. God, this is annoying. I don't understand why it keeps giving me shit.

Comment: What are the other stoage values? `VM heap & RAM`?

Comment: VM heap is 384MB & RAM is 1536MB

Comment: Did you try to create another emulator? it seems that it has some issue when it was downloaded

Comment: I have 2 emulators, but I can create a 3rd & try it out

Comment: Same issue for both of the emulators?

Comment: yeah, same issues for both

Comment: Try to build an apk, what is the size of it?

Comment: the emulator itself does look weird, so idk that might have something to do with it. I'll add an image of how it looks cuz idk how to do so in comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245050/discussion-between-abdallah-a-odeh-and-moataz-abdelraouf).

Comment: it looks normal, this how android emulators look on macOS, please try creating a new emulator and try to run the app on it

Comment: word, Ill do that & let u know how it is

Comment: its giving me a new error now, I've sent the full log in chat

Comment: Once you click on "Show advance settings" the left side of the screen is scrollable. Scroll down and Increase "Internal Storage". I've add 1500 MB and it was enough.

Answer (score 5):

I had also faced same error on windows:

`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE] Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86.`

What I done was, just wiping out the data of emulator from android studio and it worked.

[image]

here there is an option of wipe out