# android - react native - error downloading expo go app on simulator

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I try to run my react native app by command `npx expo start`. Below is the error I got while android studio simulator downloading the expo go app.

```
Error: adb: failed to install C:\Users\user\.expo\android-apk-cache\Exponent-2.28.5.apk: Failure 
[INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
```

The simulator I used: Pixel 5 API 31 Android 12.0 Google APIs x86_64

How could I fix it?

Comment: Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-to-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error-on-android). Hope this helps.